# How to get image location using php and send it to an applet?

Tags: java, php, html, image, applet

I am creating a project which is created using Applets. In my project I am using applets to create effects for the image. Initially I did the project with just 1 image stored at the same location as the files of the project.

I was calling my applet using the following code
   `<applet code=ImageFilterDemo width=1024 height=480>
    <param name=img value="<?php echo $file; ?>">`
And I passing the name of the image, which in this case is `1.jpg`

I tried to create a form which would help to select and upload the file using :

`<form action="filter.html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 Select IMAGE :  <input type="file" name="image" /> <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>`

Then I tried to get the file name of the image using a php code

`<?php $file= $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; ?>`

I am not an expert in php. I tried to see what mistake I was making but still couldn't figure out what is the mistake.

NOTE : I want the applet to load the image when the file is choosen and the upload is clicked.

Comment: Your applet runs client-side, so why would you want to upload the image to the server to use it in that applet?

Comment: So how to just use an image that the user has in their PC?

Comment: Loading a local image and loading a remote image can be very different things. Do you have the ability to modify your applet code to expect local images?

Answer (score 0):

//load an applet inside your php file like this

```
<applet code="appletname.class" height=someint width=someint>

    </applet>
and inside applet init() method
        add this line

    String str_loc=getParameter("image_file_location_set_via_php_inside_param_tag");**

    Now using HttpUrlConnection use this location to fetch the image if its over the web 

    else use
       Normal file handling
```

cheers

Answer (score -2):

W3 schools has a good tutorial on handling file uploads here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

You should save the uploaded file to a permanent location, and use that location for your applet.

Also, files are usually uploaded to a temporary, non-web-accessible directory, so when your applet requests the file by name, it can't be found because it's in the wrong directory.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, please include an explanation. It seems to me the OP isn't handling file uploads correctly, so the tutorial seems appropriate.